# How do I Pristine my Form when I leave the tab

Tags: html, css, angularjs, forms

I'm looking for an answer for this already two days. I hope you help me.

So I have my index html code:

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="citizensController as citizensCtrl">
  <h1>Moradores</h1>
  <hr>
  <uib-tabset active="activeForm">
    <!-- INICIO TAB 1 -->
    <uib-tab index="0" heading="Novo">
      <div class="animated fadeIn" data-ng-include='"templates/pages/citizens/form.html"'></div>
    </uib-tab>

    <!-- INICIO TAB NOVO -->
    <uib-tab index="1" heading="Relatório" ng-click="citizensCtrl.reportTab()">
      <div id="grid-citizens" ui-grid="citizensCtrl.gridOptions" class="grid" ng-if="    citizensCtrl.gridOptions.data"></div>
    </uib-tab>

    <!-- INICIO TAB 3 -->
    <uib-tab index="2" heading="Visão">
      Some Tab Content
    </uib-tab>
  </uib-tabset>
</div>
```

and this is the form html code:

```
<form name="citizenForm" ng-submit="citizensCtrl.createCitizen(citizenForm)" class="css-form" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="citizen_name">Nome *</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="citizen_name" placeholder="Nome" ng-model="citizensCtrl.citizen.name" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="citizen_birthday">Nascimento *</label>
    <uib-datepicker ng-model="citizensCtrl.citizen.birthday" class="well well-sm" datepicker-options="citizensCtrl.dateOptions" required></uib-datepicker>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="citizen_cell_phone">Celular *</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="citizen_cell_phone" placeholder="Celular" ng-model="citizensCtrl.citizen.cell_phone" mask='(99) 9?9999-9999' mask-restrict="reject" mask-clean="true" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="citizen_phone">Telefone *</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="citizen_phone" placeholder="Telefone" ng-model="citizensCtrl.citizen.phone" mask='(99) 9999-9999' mask-restrict="reject" mask-clean="true" required>
  </div>

  <hr>
  <h4>Endereço</h4>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="citizen_address_district">Bairro *</label>
    <select id="citizen_address_district" ng-model="citizensCtrl.citizen.address.district" class="form-control"
            ng-options="district as district.name for district in citizensCtrl.districts" ng-change="citizensCtrl.getAddresses()" required>
      <option value=""> Bairro</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="citizen_address_public_place">Rua *</label>
    <input  type="text" ng-model="citizensCtrl.citizen.address.public_place" id="citizen_address_public_place"
            uib-typeahead="address as address.public_place for address in citizensCtrl.addresses | filter:{public_place: citizensCtrl.citizen.address.public_place} | limitTo:5"
            typeahead-min-length="6" typeahead-select-on-exact="true"
            typeahead-on-select="citizensCtrl.getZipCodes()"
            typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" 
            ng-disabled="!citizensCtrl.citizen.address.district.id"
            typeahead-no-results="noResults" class="form-control" required>
    <i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
    <div ng-show="noResults">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Endereço não encontrado
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="citizen_address_zip_code">CEP *</label>
    <select id="citizen_address_zip_code" ng-model="citizensCtrl.citizen.address.zip_code"
            ng-disabled="!citizensCtrl.citizen.address.public_place.id" class="form-control"
            ng-options="zip_code as zip_code.number for zip_code in citizensCtrl.zip_codes" required>
      <option value="">CEP</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="citizen_address_number">Numero *</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="citizen_address_number" placeholder="Numero" ng-model="citizensCtrl.citizen.address.number" mask='99999999' mask-restrict="reject" mask-validate="false" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="citizen_address_complement">Complemento</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="citizen_address_complement" placeholder="Complemento" ng-model="citizensCtrl.citizen.address.complement">
  </div>

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Criar" />
  <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="citizensCtrl.defineCitizen(); citizenForm.$setPristine()" value="Limpar Formulário" />
</form>
```

and this is the function triggered in my AngularJs controller for that:

```
  self.createCitizen = function(form){
    if(form.$valid){
      $http.post(apiUrl + endpoint, angular.extend({},self.citizen)).then(function(response){
        alertsService.add('success', 'Morador criado com sucesso!');
        form.$setPristine();
        self.defineCitizen();
      }, function(error){
        alertsService.add('danger', 'Oops.. Alguma coisa deu errado. Contate o administrador.');
      });
    }else{
      alertsService.add('danger', 'Você precisa preencher todos os campos obrigatórios.');
    }
  };
```

Well, my problem occurs when I submit the formulary with some error like required items. 
Then the css changes to show what is missing. 
In this moment if I change the tab and go back to the formulary tab again the inputs should lose the css with errors, but my formulary is keeping dirty or something like that.

Comment: have you tried setting pristine on tab click?

Comment: Yes, I already tried it. But I don't have the form on tab element level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to set a `ng-if` in form looking to guide users are. If you leave the tab "Create tab" form is deleted because of `ng-if`. So when I go back to the "create" tab again, it is rebuilt.